# Setting WooCommerce product vendor from frontEnd

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Following this approach:

```
$product_information = array(
        'post_author' => wp_get_current_user()->ID,
        'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['postTitle'] ),
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'pending'
    );
 
$product_id = wp_insert_post( $product_information );

wp_set_object_terms($product_id, array('Economy'), 'product_cat');
```

I setted the product_cat taxonomy and when a product is created I receive the mail:
"Hello! A vendor ( UserTest ) has added a new product awaiting review."

Now I've tried a similar approach to insert the vendor name in the vendors column of by WP backend panel, but I'm missing something.

I was hoping that adding the  `post_author`  key in the associative array was the solution, but I was wrong.

I've tried by using:

`wp_set_object_terms($product_id, wp_get_current_user()->ID , 'taxonomy-wcpv_product_vendors');`

But nothing happened. What I am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used:

```
wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, WC_Product_Vendors_Utils::get_logged_in_vendor(), WC_PRODUCT_VENDORS_TAXONOMY );
```